# Spritekit SKTexture(rect: CGRect, in: SKTexture) issue

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktexture

I have a question which I am breaking my brains over for the last hours. I am creating a tiled map, and as textures for the tiles I have some spritesheets.

I can demonstrate my issue with the following spritesheet:
[image: spritesheet]

Now I use the SKtexture(rect: , in:) method to get the tile textures out of the spritesheet. 
My problem is that when I use this method, somehow there seems to exist a very small offset, so that when I for example want to render a map filled with the lowest left sprite (just snow) I can see a very small part of the tile above it.

I can demonstrate this with the following screenshot:

[image: example render]

As you can see, there are some blue lines between the tile rows.
This is the code I used for the example, it is an extract of the tilemap parser I use but it shows the same behaviour.

```
let source = SKTexture(imageNamed: "snowiceCor")
let superNode = SKNode()
let sourceWidth = source.size().width
let sourceHeight = source.size().height
let tileSize: CGFloat = 32.0
let tileX: CGFloat = 0
let tileY: CGFloat = 8
for i in 0...8 {
   for j in 0...8 {
        let rX = (tileSize * tileX) / sourceWidth
        let rY = CGFloat(1) - ((tileSize * tileY) / sourceHeight)
        let rW = tileSize / sourceWidth
        let rH = tileSize / sourceHeight
        let rect = CGRect(x: rX, y: rY, width: rW, height: rH)
        let texture = SKTexture(rect: rect, in: source)
        let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture, color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: tileSize, height: tileSize))
        superNode.addChild(node)
        node.zPosition = 99
        node.position.x = CGFloat(i*32)
        node.position.y = CGFloat(j*32)
    }
}
addChild(superNode)
superNode.setScale(2)
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: are your image dimensions correct?  I do not think the problem is with sprite kit, i think the issue is how you are handling your image.  First, what is sourceWidth/sourceHeight?  if this is not divisible by 32, your images are going to be off.  Second is there anti-aliasing going on in the image?  This could also be throwing off your colors.  Third did you check to make sure that the image aligns correctly so that the tiles create a seamless image? It seems they are not, which will also throw off the visuals.

Comment: thanks for thinking along, the sourceWidth and height are the dimensions of the spritesheet (texture, named snowiceCor). I made sure it is divisible by 32, the dimensions are 160*256. The example images dont align to create a seamless image, as I repeat the same tile, but this is just to demo that there is a blue line between the rows. This blue line is a result of the cropped tile texture having a small offset as it seems.

Comment: The line is not exactly blue,  The reason why I question the “blueness” is because it is not the size of a pixel, it seems to be a fraction of a pixel (which is why I also asked about anti aliasing)

Answer (score 1):

The blue line is probably anti-aliasing kicking in. You can turn this off by setting 'filteringMode = .nearest' on the textures. Alternatively (if you want the anti-aliasing), you could pad the tiles with transparent pixels).